# unable to use merge field like {!Receiving_User.FirstName} and {!Receiving_User.Username} in Visualforce email template???

Tags: visualforce, community

unable to use merge field like {!Receiving_User.FirstName} and {!Receiving_User.Username} in Visualforce email template???

I want to use VF email template as welcome email to community.

Answer (score 3):

In Salesforce Article, it's mentioned clearly currently it works with only either Text or HTML email template as below:

> These templates use unique merge fields. These merge fields are not available to select and copy when editing a template, but you can enter them manually. These merge fields will only work properly if used in a text or HTML template selected for a community.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=merge_fields_communities.htm&type=5